# Disable LINQ optimization for custom IList implementation

Tags: .net, linq

LINQ's methods `Select`, `Where`, `SelectMany` (maybe others, not sure) use optimized implementation if provided collection implements `IList<T>` interface - it does not use `GetEnumerator` method, but retrieves elements by index instead (at least in dotnet core, to avoid using enumerator overhead, I suppose).

Is there any way to disable that optimization for certain type?

I have `IList` implementation, which proxies all calls to another collection, therefore iterating all elements using enumerator is actually much faster, than getting all elements by index.

Comment: _therefore iterating all elements using enumerator is actually much faster, than getting all elements by index._ which collection supports that behavior?

Comment: The methods [`Select`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,48f64203cdc8e8cb,references), `Where`, `SelectMany` don't have this kind of optimization, only methods that  provide access to elements by index or return the `Count`, like [`ElementAt`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761,references) or [`Count`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b,references), have.

Comment: Also, why you implement `IList` at all if's better to not access it via index?

Comment: The problem in this case is that you use the wrong interface, thus breaking its contract. Implement IEnumerable if you can't support `IList<T>`'s semantics. It's not LINQ's optimizations that cause problems here, *everyone* who's going to use that class through the `IList<T>` interface will suffer

Comment: Can you please show your implementation of the `IList` or provide some code which reproduces your problem? It's hard to understand why enumerating all items is faster than getting them by index

Comment: It's IList<IWebElement> proxy in Selenium's WebDriver. Generally, by default it retrieves required elements from browser on each method call to this collections. 
This means that getting element by index from collections leads to getting elements from browser. And iterating all elements using enumerator leads to single retrieval. However, iterating using access by index leads to n calls, and therefore n elements from browser retrieval.

Comment: Couldn't you change your `IList` implementation to cache the results on first index access and access that later?

Comment: @DaveShaw 
That's possible, but not always desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Implement the given methods specifically for your type. You can provide your type specific implementations either as extension methods or as instance methods and the compiler will choose them since they are more specific (naturally extension-methods will need to be in scope in order to be considered).

An example of type specific optimizations of LINQ methods can be found targeting `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<T>`.

Comment: Yeah, but that would only work if I know the type at runtime. In my case the actual type is internal, and I only work with `IList<T>`.
I'm thinking about creating extension methods for general `IList<T>`, and check for actual type there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Linq methods that see if the collection is actually an `IList` or `ICollection` and use index access instead of an enumerator:

- `First`/`FirstOrDefault`/`Single`/`SingleOrDefault` (uses `list[0]` if no predicate is passed)
- `Last`/`LastOrDefault` (uses `list[count-1]` if no predicate is passed)
- `ElementAt`/`ElementAtOrDefault`
- `Count` (calls `ICollection.Count()` if no predicate is used)
- `Contains` (calls `ICollection.Contains`)

`Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy`, and all others will use an enumerator.

Some options are:

- Wrap your collection with an enumerator by including a `Select(x => x)` in your query if the index accessor is slower than an enumerator
- Fix the index accessors so they are performant at least in these specific cases
- Live with the inefficiency.

Comment: 1. Nope, Select, SelectMany etc wont use an enumerator, at least in dotnet core.
Take a look: 

[Select](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/143df51926f2ad397fef9c9ca7ede88e2721e801/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs)

[SelectIListIterator](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/143df51926f2ad397fef9c9ca7ede88e2721e801/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.SpeedOpt.cs) (line 256)

Comment: Therefore option 1 won't help. I can, however, wrap it into something like that  
`foreach(var e in elements)`  

`      yield return e;`

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create an IEnumerable extension function that takes an input sequence, and returns the same sequence as an IEnumerable.

See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ToEnumerable (this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
     foreach (var sourceItem in source)
         yield return sourceItem
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Person> persons = ...

var personList = persons.ToList(); // uses the fact that Persons implements IList

var otherList = persons.ToEnumerable().ToList();
// does not implement IList<...>, and thus doesn't use the optimization
```